# Posting lat/long to users table Laravel(js to mysql db)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, laravel

I'm just curious on how to do this properly. I wrote a little bit of javascript that prompts the users geolocation long and lat values. Now I want to update a users record with the long and lat values when they are ok with being asked their current location.

I know this probably has to involve some ajax but Im wondering if there is a better way.

To my knowledge the easiest would be setting up a url to receive the post request and redirect it to the usersController and have a method accept it there to save it to my database. Seems like a bit of hassle for something like 2 record values.

I don't think there is any other way but I'm still curious.

This is how I think it would go:

1. Set up ajax post request if successsful on getting the users geolocation
2. Set up a route to receive the request in my routes file
3. Set up a method in my UsersController to save the data

Correct me if I'm wrong though.

Comment: With ajax you can do that request in background without page-reload. Without ajax you can achieve that only by requesting the same route, as in ajax-way solution, but with additional page-reload. So, better way? Both has pros and cons, choose which most important to you...

Comment: from a user's standpoint i would say ajax is the way to go, even though it may seem a bit more complicated to achieve. think of the following flow.

- navigate to http://www.somesite.com
- allow said site to grab geo data
- get refresh

i would probably be bothered if i had to wait for the page to refresh so that the site owner gets data about me